# get null value for plist when get data from json and store in plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, plist

I have one application that in self get json from url and store value in .plist file.

this is my code but not working and my plist file in null (guide me,please)

this my json :

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Apple Releases iPad 3",
        "article": "This week Apple Inc. released the third gen iPad. It's available now for $599. It comes in 2 models: 8GB and 16GB.",
        "timestamp": "1343782587",
        "date_string": "Tue, Jul 31st, 2012 @ 7:56"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Microsoft Releases Windows 8",
        "article": "Last week Microsoft released Windows 8 for consumer purchase. It's available now starting at $99 for the Home version. It comes with Microsoft Office '12 already installed.",
        "timestamp": "1343782649",
        "date_string": "Tue, Jul 31st, 2012 @ 7:57"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Blizzard Announces Diablo IV",
        "article": "This week, long-time Diablo fans are euphoric with excitement at the announcement of Diablo IV, which will be released this fall, for $20! This original $20 purchase will also include all future expansion packs.",
        "timestamp": "1343782742",
        "date_string": "Tue, Jul 31st, 2012 @ 7:59"
    }
]

-(NSString*)docsDir {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,
     NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]; 
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.109/mamal/json.php"];
     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
     NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
     [con start];  
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
     data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init]; 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)theData {
     [data appendData:theData]; 
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
     [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
      name = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
      for (int i =0; i<[name count]; i++) {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table indexPathForSelectedRow];
      n = [[name objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)+i]objectForKey:@"title"];
      if(!add){
            add = [NSMutableArray array];
       }
       [add addObject:n];
         }
       NSLog(@"add : %@",add);
       listPath = [[self docsDir]stringByAppendingFormat:@"janatan.plist"];    
       array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:listPath];
       [array addObjectsFromArray:add];
       [array writeToFile:listPath atomically:YES];
       NSLog(@"array : %@",array);         //array is null :(
       [table reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: listPath = [[self docsDir]stringByAppendingFormat:@"janatan.plist"]; --> IS THIS WHAT IS NULL

Comment: no my friend I have 3 value in "add" but "array" is null . [array addObjectFromArray:add]; look this code!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your JSON, my guess is that you have some Type of object or data structure that does not conform with the specified types.

- The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
- All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray,
  NSDictionary, or NSNull.
- All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
- Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

If your JSON does not fit these guidelines it will fail when you try and convert it to a pList.

First for error checking try

```
 isValidJSONObject:
```

on your "data" object and see what you get.

Next you are doing too much work the NSJSONSerialization should return back a foundation object of which you can write directly to a plist.

For example if what you get back is a NSDictionary object you can use

```
writeToFile:atomically:
```

Which I think you try, but you alter the data quite a bit before you do.

Comment: It appears you are getting back an array of dictionaries.

Comment: my friend I could write nsarray in plist file with help this code :if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:listPath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:listPath error:nil];
        NSLog(@"create this");
    } but this place I can not why???

Comment: I don't see the code you listed in the comment in your question

Comment: Also, where is "add" declared in your code...it's not in your example. This would cause an issue if you never declared it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to be a lot more descriptive in what is not working.

Secondly, break the problem down, either check with the debugger or with NSLog, all the intermediate products.

Log the data you get in didReceiveData

Are you getting into connectionDidFinishLoading

What do you have in data when you do get into connectionDidFinishLoading

What is name.count?

Is the array you're loading from disk valid?  You have to have an empty plist to load before you can start appending to it. ( This is the only thing that looks like an error to me).

General points: you could improve your naming, what is add???
I'd add more code documentation too, this looks mostly valid code, but the logic is rather confusing.

Hope this helps
Gordon

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is due to the  way listPath is created, you should use `stringByAppendingPathComponent`: instead `stringByAppendingFormat`: .

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    name = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data 
                                           options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments 
                                             error:nil];
    if(!add){
         NSMutableArray *add = [NSMutableArray array];
    }

    for (int i =0; i<[name count]; i++) {
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.table indexPathForSelectedRow];
         n = name[indexPath.row+i][@"title"];
         [add addObject:n];
    }

    NSLog(@"add : %@",add);

    listPath = [[self docsDir]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"janatan.plist"];

    NSMutableArray *savedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:listPath];
    if (!savedArray) {
        savedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    [savedArray addObjectsFromArray:add];

    [savedArray writeToFile:listPath atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"array : %@",savedArray); 
    [self.table reloadData]; 

}
```